# How do you default to the empty_value choice in a custom symfony form field type?

Tags: symfony

I have a created a custom form field dropdown list for filtering by year. One of the things I want to do is to allow the user to filter by all years, which is the default option. I am adding this as an `empty_value`. However, when I render the form, it defaults on the first item that's not the empty value. The empty value is there, just above it in the list. How do I make the page default to, in my case 'All' when the page initially loads? Code is below.

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class YearType extends AbstractType
{

  private $yearChoices;

  public function __construct()
  {
      $thisYear = date('Y');
      $startYear = '2012';

      $this->yearChoices = range($thisYear, $startYear);
  }

  public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
  {
    return array(
        'empty_value' => 'All',
        'choices' => $this->yearChoices,
    );
  }

  public function getParent(array $options)
  {
    return 'choice';
  }

  public function getName()
  {
    return 'year';
  }
}
```

I'm rendering my form in twig with a simple `{{ form_widget(filter_form) }}`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try adding `empty_data` option to `null`, so it comes first. I have many fields of this type and it's working, for example:

```php
class GenderType extends \Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType
{

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'empty_data'  => null,
            'empty_value' => "Non specificato",
            'choices'     => array('m' => 'Uomo', 'f' => 'Donna'),
            'required'    => false,
        );
    }

    public function getParent(array $options) { return 'choice'; }

    public function getName() { return 'gender'; }

}
```

**EDIT**: Another possibility (i suppose) would be setting [`preferred_choices`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#preferred-choices). This way you'll get "All" option to the top. But i don't know if it can work with `null` `empty_data`, but you can change `empty_data` to whatever you want:

```php
  public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
  {
    return array(
        'empty_value'       => 'All',
        'empty_data'        => null,
        'choices'           => $this->yearChoices,
        'preferred_choices' => array(null)         // Match empty_data
    );
  }
```

Comment: Hmm... it works now and I'm not sure why. I think I had to clear my cache or something? The `All` options were showing at the top, but the selected one was 2nd or something. Now it's properly defaulting to the top option.

Comment: @Squazic well, that's ok :) Maybe it's caching or maybe you didn't reloaded the entire page...

Comment: I got this to work by adding `empty_value` and `empty_data` but now the user can skip all required validation and submit without picking any of the actually valid options.

Answer (score 0):

When I've needed a simple cities dropwdown from database without using relations, I've ended up using this config for city field (adding null as first element of choices array), as `empty_data` param didn't do work for me:

```
$builder->add('city',
    ChoiceType::class,
    [
        'label'        => 'ui.city',
        'choices'      => array_merge([null], $this->cityRepository->findAll()),
        'choice_label' => static function (?City $city) {
            return null === $city ? '' : $city->getName();
        },
        'choice_value' => static function(?City $city) {
            return null === $city ? null : $city->getId();
        },
    ]);
```